# How do I get a really black background?

Tags: dslr, portrait, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I need to get photos with a unifom black background (not with post)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7762/what-do-i-need-to-get-photos-with-a-unifom-black-background-not-with-post)

How can I get a pure black background when taking portraits, just like in following picture?

[image]

For example, in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nk9cTa3UthM) video Mark Wallace is using inverse square law, to get that effect, but when I try, my background is not black, as it should be. Where I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: For a comment on this subject with particular reference to this image, see my recent answer to [**What do I need to get photos with a unifom black background {not with post}?**)](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7762/what-do-i-need-to-get-photos-with-a-unifom-black-background-not-with-post/34164#34164). I note that your question can be read as suggesting that the background in this picture has been achieved "in camera" - but you may in fact be only using it as an example of a black background, and not saying that it was necessarily achieved in-camera.