# What lighting equipment to purchase for under $50?

Tags: lighting, lighting-basics, reflectors

I'm an enthusiastic beginner with Canon 550D, shooting both stills and videos, indoors and outdoors.

My biggest problem is strong shades and insufficient light when photographing people. I figured out that the solution is some basic lighting equipment.

My current wishlist is:

- [Neewer 110CM 43" 5-in-1 Collapsible Multi-Disc Light Reflector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002ZIMEMW) ($9.46)

[image]

- [Some kind of lightbulb](http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/photo/3347871/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_p_1_3)

**On a budget of $25-$50, what general-purpose lighting equipment should I buy?**

Comment: Please create the "reflector" tag and add it to my question.

Comment: I've created the tag, but isn't this question a duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/what-lighting-equipment-should-i-get-on-a-very-tight-budget? (Except with an even more restricted budget?)

Comment: Isn't the budget a serious difference?

Comment: $150 and $50 are both on the order of "basically no money at all for an expensive hobby". :) I think that realistically, though, any answer that would apply to the lower amount could be part of the answer for the higher value, and any answer for the higher value which exceeds your limit is still helpful because it provides context for what you could do with just slightly more money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With that type of a budget, you are much better going the DIY route**, putting in some of your own time instead of your own money.

For portrait photography, you can find a huge benefit to having a beauty dish. I made one of these myself for only a few dollars. You can find examples of how to do so on many internet forums, but here is [one example](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-Beauty-Dish-flash-modifier/).
These were the materials I used:
[image]

You could also do things like

- [DIY Light Diffuser](http://www.instructables.com/id/10-Minute-Light-Diffuser/)
- [DIY Softbox](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Softbox/)
- [DIY Gary Fong Lightsphere](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Gary-Fong-Lightsphere/)
- DIY Light tent for product photography(Google has many options)

Just take a look at the instructables website, or Google the lighting accessories that are mentioned in [this thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/what-lighting-equipment-should-i-get-on-a-very-tight-budget) and see if you can make it yourself on the cheap.

Instead of going to an expensive photography shop, think of the hardware store as your new photography store, you can find many many things that will suffice just fine for non-professional use.

Comment: hows your DIY one work? This has been on my list of projects to do, but I can't convince myself to do it

Comment: @rfusca I think the results are very good. I don't have any great way to support it though, so I just end up holding it by hand at the moment. If you can figure out that part of it, it would be great.

Answer (score 4):

I was in your situation and after playing arond with some light bulbs and a borrowed manual flash I've discovered that (unsurprisingly) a flash is better.

You can get a YN480 flash on eBay for arond $40 - it's a manual flash, that means you have to put the camera on manual mode and adjust exposure and flash power manually (but it's easier than it sounds, I can get the correct settings with just 2-3 test shots, and I'm not an expert).

Or, you can do what I did and get the YN485, that's a TTL flash, that's means you get the correct flash power automatically on every shot, but it's just a little bit above your budget.

You point the flash at the cieling or a nearby wall and use it as a reflector to get nice soft light.

You can easily make a DIY reflector from stuff you already have or from really cheap items you can pick up at and hardware store, so I wouldn't buy it unless you have the money to pay for the conviniance of a folding reflector (the same goes for softboxes and most other light modifiers).

Answer (score 1):

With such a tight budget every penny counts. Instead of getting the 5-in-1 reflector I recommend saving $9 and just getting a sheet of white posterboard. Alternatively save $7 and get a sheet of white foamcore.

With the remaining budget I think you're basically limited to using standard high-wattage CFL light bulbs in clamp lights like can be found at a hardware store. Then get a piece of [iced acrylic](http://www.homedepot.com/Lighting-Fans-Indoor-Lighting-Indoor-Lighting-Accessories-Fluorescent-Lighting-Accessories/h_d1/N-5yc1vZbvm5/R-202193056/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&storeId=10051) to clamp over the light to diffuse it for softer light.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look on Amazon at YN 462 it's under $35, I have two of YN 460 and I love them. Add to it a white umbrella for around $7 and if you can stretch your budget a few more dollars, you can also buy a light stand for about $12.

Comment: Can I use it for videos?

Comment: Nope, only for photos.